# ToolBarの透過の際のBarButtonItemの非透過について

Tags: objective-c, iphone

InterfaceBuilderでToolBar,BarButtonItemを配置しています。
ToolBarをalphaを下げて透過させる際にBarButtonItemなどを配置するとBarButtonItemも透過されてしまうのですが、ToolBarのみ透過させてBarButtonItemは透過させない方法はありますか。また、自分で作成した画像をBarButtonItemの画像とする際の非透過させる処理も知りたいです。

知っている方がいましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://smallmakeprgnote.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/カスタムtoolbarの背景を透明にする/](https://smallmakeprgnote.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0toolbar%E3%81%AE%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF%E3%82%92%E9%80%8F%E6%98%8E%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468831/couldnt-uitoolbar-be-transparent)

`UIToolbar`のサブクラスを作って、処理するということですね。